# What exactly is the "from" attribute for while using Nodemailer?

Tags: node.js, smtp, nodemailer

I am new to Nodemailer and just set it up to send emails for a project. I am confused about the function of "from" attribute in the sendMail function. The "to" attribute specifies the receiver's address. In the documentation it says that "from" is the sender's address, but the email received to the receiver nowhere even mentions the address in "from". Instead, the sender's email is the one which was specified in the "auth" field of the transporter.
It makes sense because that is the id using which SMTP is sending the email. But, then, what is the use of the address in "from" attribute? Irrespective of what I put in it, the email is sent.